# SpringCloud release planning (Brixton)

Tags: spring-cloud

Do you have any dates for a first RC of the Brixton release train?

SpringBoot 1.3.0 has evolved and contains many fixes and features that we (and probably many other people) require.
In addition, many bugs and issues have been fixed in Spring cloud since Angel.SR3. Not being able to build our software on a fixed release (other than a SNAPSHOT) is a killer for us :-(

In general, it would be very helpful if SpringCloud adopt a faster release cycle with more frequent RCs or Milestones so bug fixes are available sooner. This is quite important for young projects like this one where a high number of issues are likely to appear early in its life.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: We will have a milestone before spring one (which is mid sept).

Comment: Will this Milestone be based on SpringBoot 1.3.x?
If not, when do you plan to provide an initial milestone for that version?

Comment: It has been based on 1.3.0 for a while now.

Comment: @spencergibb just noticed that most `spring-cloud` projects have been released in M1 - but (yet) not `spring-cloud-starter-parent`. Is it on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

SpringCloud 1.1.0.M1 has been made available September 14th. Based on SpringBoot 1.3.0.M5